# Converting audio file in base64String in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I am recording an audio file using following code.

```
let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("tt.mp4")

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]
    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()
    } catch {
        print(" startRecording fail ")
    }
```

Now when user stops the recording I want to save the audio file in a base64 string. I am trying with the following code:

```
let audioData =  try? Data(contentsOf: (audioRecorder?.url)!)
    let encodedString = audioData?.base64EncodedString()
    print(" data \(encodedString)")
    //"AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1wNDJpc29t"
```

Now I am trying to play the string:

```
let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(data:(encodedString?.data(using: String.Encoding.init(rawValue: 0)))!)
    player?.prepareToPlay()
    player?.play()
```

It's not playing. Where I am missing?

Comment: The `encodedString?.data(using: String.Encoding.init(rawValue: 0))` seems extremely suspicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an error in your last code snippet where you try to convert the base64 encoded string back to raw data.

I haven't tried running the code with actual audio data, but this should at least fix your data conversion error:

```
if let encodedString = encodedString, let data = Data(base64Encoded: encodedString) {
    let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(data: data)
    player?.prepareToPlay()
    player?.play()
}
```